# Part of the range formatted as text

Tags: excel, vba

Following the answer by @Pᴇʜ in this link [Merging two macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53432881/merging-two-macros)

I have an additional challenge.
Within the Named Range called "RawTab1" the column J contains values "Year" formatted as **'2018** and in the column K contains values "Months" formatted as **'12** [image: see screenshot].

I use the macro by @Pᴇʜ to copy the rng "RawTab1" to the Table called "DataTable" in the sheet called "Data"

So my question is:

- Is it possible to paste these two columns formatted as numbers?

Otherwise the macro is working perfect.

Comment: This isn't a forum.  The @ sign doesn't work the way you think it does.  It probably doesn't work this way even in forums.

Comment: You cannot do this while copy/paste. You need to do it before or after. Therefore you need to loop through the whole column and check each cell if it has a `'` as first letter and convert it. This will be a completely new macro and has nothing to do with your first one. Give it a try on your own. If you get stuck or errors [edit] your question and add your code.

Comment: RobertHarvey, I'm new here but it is noted
@Pᴇʜ, the ' is not copied into the table but still the columns are not treated as numbers?

Comment: Then just select the columns and chose a number format or select `general`.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ is it posible to multiply the values in columns Year and Month with *1 after the paste and thus convert them to numbers?

Comment: You can loop through the column and do that if my previous comment didn't help.

Comment: The columns are already formatted as `general` but still not converted as numbers I have also tried to format them as `number` but not working. Only by Paste Special and multiply then they convert to numbers

Comment: @NewCalc Then do that with these both columns. Macro Recorder can help.

Comment: I have tried with rec macro but i'm not sure how to incorporate the recorded macro into the macro done by you?

Comment: you need to run it afterwards.

Comment: `Sub ConvertToNumberYearMOnth()
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("DataTable").ListColumns(10).DataBodyRange.Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlMultiply, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub` I get an 400 error, any idea why ?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Public Sub Combined()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
    sht.Range("A3:M3", sht.Range("A3:M3").End(xlDown)).ClearContents

    With Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("RawTab1")
        'copy everything from RawTab1 but not the first 2 rows
        Dim Crng As Range
        Set Crng = .Resize(RowSize:=.Rows.Count - 2).Offset(RowOffset:=2)
    End With

    sht.Range("A2").Resize(Crng.Rows.Count, Crng.Columns.Count).Value = _
         sht.Evaluate("IF(ISNUMBER(--" & Crng.Address(0, 0, xlA1, 1) & "),--" & Crng.Address(0, 0, xlA1, 1) & "," & Crng.Address(0, 0, xlA1, 1) & ")")

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Scott, the macro is working fine but the performance is very slow.
Any idea how it could be optimised?

Comment: If possible to restrict the macro to run the conversion only on the two columns not for the entire range?